# Rails, undefined method error. But I can use this method in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my rspec testing. I got NoMethodError:
           undefined method `password_digest='.

But in rails console. I do can use .password_digest method.

I am so confused. I searched google. Got sever threads about this. even in stackoverflow. But those don't help. I do have password_digest as a field in my database.

I can even set my password_digest

see:

```
1.9.2-p290 :005 > user.password_digest
 => "$2a$10$X8CSsstOqZKKA6qVHpW9.uH5Lzd7dxfGNCAxvIbePpcfBg8KFbD4y" 
1.9.2-p290 :006 > user.password_digest = 1
 => 1 
1.9.2-p290 :007 > user.password_digest
 => 1
```

And also, in my app. everything seems fine. That's weird.
Please help...

```
1.9.2-p290 :002 > User.first.password_digest
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
 => "$2a$10$NCfX2SgKeqGARJ68StxRJuCbbbK7g18n5FPxbHY5THwg4pAdHUvui" 
1.9.2-p290 :003 > 
[5]+  Stopped                 rails console
luke@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/RoR/rails_projects/sample_app2012$ bundle exec rspec spec/models/user_spec.rb

DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in #<Class:0x000001029f6688> instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/luke/Documents/workspace/RoR/rails_projects/sample_app2012/spec/models/user_spec.rb:14)
DEPRECATION WARNING: The InstanceMethods module inside ActiveSupport::Concern will be no longer included automatically. Please define instance methods directly in #<Class:0x000001029f6688> instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/luke/Documents/workspace/RoR/rails_projects/sample_app2012/spec/models/user_spec.rb:14)
FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

Failures:

  1) User 
     Failure/Error: @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com",
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `password_digest=' for #<User:0x00000100beee60>
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17:in `new'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
..... There are 19 more failures, to save space, i didn't paste them here.
```

And this is my user_spec.rb code:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null
#

require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  before(:each) do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", 
                     password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
  end



  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest)}
  it { should respond_to(:password)}
  it { should respond_to(:password_confirmation)}
  it { should respond_to(:remember_token) }
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate) }

  it { should be_valid }

  describe "when name is not present" do
    before { @user.name = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when name is too long" do
    before { @user.name = "a" * 51 }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when email format is valid" do
    valid_addresses = %w[user@foo.com THE_USER@foo.bar.org first.last@foo.jp]
    valid_addresses.each do |valid_address|
        before { @user.email = valid_address}
        it {should be_valid }
    end
  end

  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
        user_with_same_email = @user.dup
        user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
        user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "when password is not present" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = " " }
    it {should_not be_valid}
  end

  describe "when password doesn't match confirmation" do
    before { @user.password_confirmation = "mismatch" }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
        it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
        let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

        it { should_not == user_for_invalid_password }
        specify { user_for_invalid_password.should be_false }
    end

    describe "remember token" do
      before { @user.save }
      its(:remember_token) { should_not be_blank }
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my user.rb under modles:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id         :integer         not null, primary key
#  name       :string(255)
#  email      :string(255)
#  created_at :datetime        not null
#  updated_at :datetime        not null



class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation



  validates :name, presence: true, :length => { maximum: 50 }
  valid_email_regex = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, :presence   => true,
                    :format     => { with: valid_email_regex },
                    :uniqueness => { case_sensitive: false }


  validates :password,  length: { minimum: 6}
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class User has method password_diges but has no method password_digest=
this is not the same methods, so instance of User shall not be responsible on password_digest
it shoud return password_digest but should_not respond_to password_digest i think

Answer (score 6):

Was just stuck on this for a while as well.

Don't forget

`rake db:test:prepare` after new migrations!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `User.first.password_digest` in console because `password_digest` and `password_digest=` isn't the same methods.

`password_digest=` same as:

```
    def password_digest=(digest)
      @password_digest = digest
    end
```

otherwise `password_digest`:

```
    def password_digest
      @password_digest
    end
```

Comment: this will lose the password_digest

Comment: it's just explanation the difference

Answer (score 0):

In your console, you're trying the `password_digest` method, not the `password_digest=` method. Are you able to execute the following in the console? `User.first.password_digest = "$2a$10$NCfX2SgKeqGARJ68StxRJuCbbbK7g18n5FPxbHY5THwg4pAdHUvui"`

I think your issue may be rooted in the fact that you're specifying only certain attributes in your `User` model as being `attr_accessible`. Try adding `:password_digest` to that list and see if your test passes.

Comment: And you can set a `password_digest` for a user in the console?

Comment: Yes I can.    1.9.2-p290 :005 > user.password_digest
 => "$2a$10$X8CSsstOqZKKA6qVHpW9.uH5Lzd7dxfGNCAxvIbePpcfBg8KFbD4y" 
1.9.2-p290 :006 > user.password_digest = 1
 => 1 
1.9.2-p290 :007 > user.password_digest
 => 1

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am new to RoR and I learned RailsTutorial and encountered this issue too. After a long search in Google I found my db/test.sqlite3 hasn't been updated. which means there was 'password_digest' in my db/development.sqlite3 but there wasn't that column in my db/test.sqlite3.
And after I run the command  'rake db:reset' and 'rake db:test:prepare', the issue was gone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same issue yesterday. The console in development and in test environment work well. And the web app itself works great as well. But the test (almost the same test as the question described) fail for `no method` error.

I've tried to stop spring, recreate test database, kill memcached. But it doesn't work.

Finally, I added some data into the fixture file `test/fixtures/users.yml`.

```
harry:
  name: Harry
  email: harry@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

It was empty before. Then the tests passed. I made the `user.yml` empty afterwards.The tests still passed.

I don't know why yet. But hope it helps.